# What needs to be overridden in a struct to ensure equality operates properly?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, operators, equals-operator

As the title says: do I need to override the `==` operator? how about the `.Equals()` method? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Also watch out for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null/21962298 -- if you're not careful then comparison of your struct (a value type) to null will compile just fine but not do what you expect.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

An example from msdn

```
public struct Complex 
{
   double re, im;
   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
        return obj is Complex c && this == c;
   }
   public override int GetHashCode() 
   {
      return re.GetHashCode() ^ im.GetHashCode();
   }
   public static bool operator ==(Complex x, Complex y) 
   {
      return x.re == y.re && x.im == y.im;
   }
   public static bool operator !=(Complex x, Complex y) 
   {
      return !(x == y);
   }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it woldn't be better for performance to use `Complex other = obj as Complex` and then check if `other == null` instead of using `is` and then a cast...

Comment: @Clement: You can't do that for a struct; the result can't be null. You'd get a compile error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think one could use `Complex? other = obj as Complex?`, but nullable types are often not amenable to efficiency.

Comment: This is good style. Be aware, however, that `System.ValueType` already overrides `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` in a way that is equivalent to what we see above. So if you removed your two overrides from the `struct` above, it would still work the same. (I still agree it is fine to include the "redundant" overrides.)

Comment: You should also check the Type, otherwise if II have an X of type MyComplex derived from Complex, and an Y of type Complex, then X == Y might return something different then Y == X

Comment: Is it safe to directly compare doubles (`x.re == y.re && x.im == y.im`)?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse - Value types in naturally sealed so it's not possible to derive a `MyComplex` as you suggest.

Comment: Why not obj is SaveOptions op && this == op; ?

Answer (score 47):

You should also implement IEquatable<T>. Here is an excerpt from Framework Design Guidelines:

> DO implement IEquatable on value types.
>   The  Object.Equals  method  on  value  types  causes  boxing,  and  its 
>   default  implementation  is not very effcient because  it uses refection. 
>   IEquatable.Equals can offer much better performance and can be 
>   implemented so that it does not cause boxing.

```
public struct Int32 : IEquatable<Int32> {
    public bool Equals(Int32 other){ ... }
}
```

> DO follow the same guidelines as for
>   overriding Object.Equals when 
>   implementing IEquatable.Equals. 
>   See section 8.7.1 for detailed
>   guidelines on overriding Object.Equals

Comment: So this is only used on value types? (not reference?)

Comment: Because reference types do not need to be boxed when passed as object, ergo, IEquatable<T> would not provide any benefit.  Value types are usually copied fully onto the stack (or into the outer types layout), so to get an object reference to it, and correctly handle the lifetime of the object, it needs to be boxed (wrapped with a special type) and copied to the heap; only then the reference to the heap object can be passed to a function like Object.Equals.

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunetely I don't have enough reputation to comment other entries. So I'm posting possible enhancement to the top solution here.

Correct me, if i'm wrong, but implementation mentioned above

```
public struct Complex 
{
   double re, im;
   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
      return obj is Complex && this == (Complex)obj;
   }
   public override int GetHashCode() 
   {
      return re.GetHashCode() ^ im.GetHashCode();
   }
   public static bool operator ==(Complex x, Complex y) 
   {
      return x.re == y.re && x.im == y.im;
   }
   public static bool operator !=(Complex x, Complex y) 
   {
      return !(x == y);
   }
}
```

Has major flaw. I'm refering to

```
  public override int GetHashCode() 
   {
      return re.GetHashCode() ^ im.GetHashCode();
   }
```

XORing is symmetrical, so Complex(2,1) and Complex(1,2) would give same hashCode.

We should probably make something more like:

```
  public override int GetHashCode() 
   {
      return re.GetHashCode() * 17 ^ im.GetHashCode();
   }
```

Comment: Having hashcode collisions is not necessarily a problem. In fact you will always have a chance of a collision (read up on pigion holes/birthday paradox) In your case Complex(1,4) and Complex(4,1) collide (admittedly there were less collisions) it depends on your data. The hashcode is used to quickly weed out 99.999% of the unwanted objects (e.g., in a dictionary) The equality operators  have the final say.

Comment: That been said the more properties you have on the struct, there is a bigger chance of a collision. This may be a better hash algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/309634

Comment: @DarcyThomas That doesn't mean you should be outright dismissing collision probabilities, especially in data structures that expect redundancy. You could potentially be generating far more 0-hashes than you reasonably should be and for what benefit exactly? At a certain point, intentionally crippling uniqueness defeats the entire purpose of generating the hash.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the time you can avoid implementing Equals and GetHashcode in structs - because there is an automatic implementation by the compiler for Value types using bitwise content + reflection for reference members.

Have a look at that post : 
[Which is best for data store Struct/Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951186/which-is-best-for-data-store-struct-classes/32797530#32797530)

So for ease of use you could still implement == and !=.

But most of the time you can avoid implementing Equals and GetHashcode.
A case where you'd have to implement Equals and GetHashCode is for a field that you don't wan't to take into account.
For instance a field that varies as time goes by like Age of a Person or instantSpeed of a car( the identity of the object shouldn't change if you want to find it back in the dictionary at the same place)

Regards, best code

Comment: Reflection is a lot slower compared to a manual implementation. If you care about performance, DO write them manually.

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference among the two is that the `==` operator is static, i.e. the appropriate method to invoke is determined at compile time, while the `Equals` method is invoked dinamically on an instance.
Defining both is probably the best thing to do, even if this matters less in the case of structs, since structs cannot be extended (a struct can't inherit from another).

Answer (score 3):

Just for completness I would also advice to overload `Equals` method:

```
public bool Equals(Complex other) 
{
   return other.re == re && other.im == im;
}
```

this is a real spead improvement as there is no boxing occuring of the input argument of `Equals(Object obj)` method

Some best prac­tices for using value types:

- make them immutable
- over­ride Equals (the one that takes an object as argument);
- over­load Equals to take another instance of the same value type (e.g. * Equals(Complex other));
- over­load oper­a­tors == and !=;
- over­ride GetHashCode

This comes from this post: http://theburningmonk.com/2015/07/beware-of-implicit-boxing-of-value-types/