# When should a tree structure be class/struct?

Tags: c#, tree, struct

What are the criteria on which to decide when a tree node should be a struct or a class?

Answer (score 1):

i would go for class becuase you can pass node as reference but not on the struct which will be passed as a copy of original

and you would require a lot of manupulation on nodes so passing them as a reference sometime results in performance boostup.

and if you are storing a lot of data in the your node tahn struct would not be a choice.

i am not pointing out which is more faster value or refernce types that totally depends on scenarios.

Comment: I go for classes also on a regular basis. I rarely use structs. But is just a personal preferance.

Answer (score 0):

Structs are usually more lightweight and are considered value types. Classes are reference types.

Consider this post also: [Which is best for data store Struct/Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951186/which-is-best-for-data-store-struct-classes)

Comment: The term "lightweight" is a bit misleading in this context. As structs are always copied when passed around, larger structs can be quite "heavyweight". In .NET you almost always want to use a class unless you are doing P/Invoke or you have the rare case that you need a custom value type.

Comment: Please see my comment to saurabh.

Answer (score 0):

While modifying the tree, you need at least 2 pointers/references to the same "data", this is hard to do with structs, unless you box (convert to object) them explicitly.