# Would a struct be a good choice for storing a group of values?

Tags: c#, class, struct

Consider the following C# class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set}
    public int Age {get;set}
}
```

I will only be using this for passing along a couple variables in a function with a single parameter - would using a struct be a better approach?

Edit: I dont care if the values change, they are not supposed to change anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your expectation of what should happen after you pass in the values.
If you don't care about the changes in the values being retained after the function call finishes, you could make it a struct, but if you want the function which takes a person argument to make changes and the caller should see it, use a class .

Also, if this is part of a domain model / data layer I'd stick with a class.

Comment: Copying from my last comment: So, I should pick a struct, based on the fact that I am just grouping some values together?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't see any reason why you couldn't use a struct. Of course, you may also have to think about identity. If two instances of the Person have the same values, does it mean they are the same person?

Comment: Equality is not required in this case - I am merely passing along values to be transformed with XML :)

Comment: If you use a ref struct you will see the changes, so that's not really a reason to base a choice on?

Answer (score 2):

From the bottom of Eric Lippert's excellent ["the stack is an implementation detail"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx):

> I’d always make the choice of value type vs reference type based on whether the type is *semantically* representing a value or *semantically* a reference to something.

That is, how would equality be defined between two `Person` variables - if they contain the same *values*, or they are two references to a single instance?

Comment: So, I should pick a struct, based on the fact that I am just grouping some values together?

Answer (score 1):

Its depends upon your requirement. If you dont want to inherit and dont want any modification within the object (since its value type), then you can go ahead with struct.

otherwise class is best in all the way especially to apply inheritance concepts.

may be this is duplicate to: [Which is best for data store Struct/Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951186/which-is-best-for-data-store-struct-classes?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx):

> A class is a reference type. When an object of the class is created, the variable to which the object is assigned holds only a reference to that memory. When the object reference is assigned to a new variable, the new variable refers to the original object. Changes made through one variable are reflected in the other variable because they both refer to the same data.
>
> A struct is a value type. When a struct is created, the variable to which the struct is assigned holds the struct's actual data. When the struct is assigned to a new variable, it is copied. The new variable and the original variable therefore contain two separate copies of the same data. Changes made to one copy do not affect the other copy.
>
> In general, classes are used to model more complex behavior, or data that is intended to be modified after a class object is created. Structs are best suited for small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created.

Answer (score 1):

my rule of thumb;

- Use a class untill you need millions and need a struct to save on storage

Among others, using structs will make this not work;

- List[x].Name ="NewName";

Comment: No, but if one uses a struct, `var temp=List[x]; temp.Name="NewName"; List[x]=temp;` will work and have the expected effects.  If one uses a mutable class, `List[x].Name="NewName";` will compile and will do something, but one may have to examine a lot of code in order to determine its full effect (in particular, what other references to the modified object exist).

Comment: the temp method works, but is ugly. And the code shown will compile, but just not do what you would expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to use a simple struct with public fields (not properties).  The beautiful thing about such structs is that they all behave identically aside from the names and types of their fields.  Given an array `MyPeople[]` of a struct `Person` with exposed field `Name`, one can know that `MyPeople[0].Name = "George";` will have no effect upon `MyPeople[1].Name`.  By contrast, if `Person` were an otherwise-identical class, there would be no such guarantee.  Even if `Person` were a struct with a read-write property `Name`, one wouldn't know without looking at its definition whether or not the property would actually behave like a struct field, or whether it would access something stored in a class object.

Note that the reasons which might cause one to generally favor properties over fields do not apply to simple structs.  If an object `Fred` holds a field `George` of a class type, and has exposed to the outside world a reference to the object referred to thereby, the only way `Fred` can know that `George`'s properties won't change without its knowledge or consent is if the code for class `George` won't let those properties change without, at minimum, letting `Fred` know about (in many cases, it's simplest for `George` to simply promise that it won't let its properties change under any circumstances).  By contrast, if `Fred` holds a field `Ronald` of an exposed-field struct type, there is no way that any of `Ronald`'s fields will change without `Fred`'s knowledge and consent.  Since nobody but `Fred` can manipulate those fields, and since `Fred` will know what it requires of the struct, it's simplest to simply have `Fred` be the one responsible for maintaining any desired invariants.