# The program doesn't run throughout the code

Tags: c#

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
namespace MATRIX_algebra
{
    public struct Struct_matrix
    {
        List<List<double>> entries; 
        public Struct_matrix(List<List<double>> values)
        {
            entries = values;
        }
    }
//    public delegate void process_matrix(Struct_matrix matrix);

    public class Matrix_init
    {
        public int size_C, size_R;


        public void matrix_size()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of the matrix ");
            Console.WriteLine("rows? ");
            this.size_R = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("columns? ");
            this.size_C = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public List<List<double>> values = new List<List<double>>();                       
        public void matrix_value()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.size_R; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the entries of the {0} row  ",i+1);
                for (int j = 0; j < this.size_C; j++)
                {
                    values[i][j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Struct_matrix matrix_init = new Struct_matrix(values);
        }
    }
}        


namespace test
{   
    using MATRIX_algebra;
    public class test_values
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            Matrix_init matrix1 = new Matrix_init();
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.size_R; i++)
            {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.size_C; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(matrix1.values[i][j]);
            }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

I feel so dumb with this question, but I really need help since I'm just beginner

I don't know why when I run the program, it doesn't run through some parts of the code.

I debugged it, Main() -> instantiate Matrix_init ->public List> values = new List>(); -> end the program.

Comment: In the future please come up with a better title; we shouldn't have to open the question to understand the title.

Comment: It doesn't run through because you are not calling it. Having methods is not enough, you need to call them manually. I do not see any call to matrix_size or matrix_value anywhere, you're only creating the class.

Comment: Side note: unless you understand what you are doing *don't use* `struct`. Please check questions about "struct vs. class" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951186/which-is-best-for-data-store-struct-classes.

Comment: @DourHighArch it does garner interest though to be fair

Answer (score 3):

You need a constructor change `public void matrix_size()` to:

```
public Matrix_init()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of the matrix ");
    Console.WriteLine("rows? ");
    this.size_R = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("columns? ");
    this.size_C = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

And this program is **running** Just it doesn't work as expected.Because `matrix_size()` method is never called so the `size_R` and `size_C` is never assigned to a value.They will have the default value for int which is *zero*, and that's why your program never enters the `for` loop.Instead of adding constructor you can also simply call the `matrix_size()` method.

```
Matrix_init matrix1 = new Matrix_init();
matrix1.matrix_size();
```

And then call the `matrix_value()` method to get inputs from user and assign the values of your matrix array.Remember all methods needs to be call, they won't do anything if you don't call them.