# Performance: should method return a class or struct?

Tags: c#, performance, class, struct

Recently moved from python to C#. Developing math app.
Looked through many questions at SO about class vs struct, so I would like an advice from experienced people regarding performance.

**DETAILS**

I have a method, and during its execution 6 double variables are calculated and about 6 double[] arrays of same lenght. I want my method to return all them "packed" into one variable. Not planning to change them, I just need a storage and acces to them. During execution of the app, method will be called many times, such storages will be created many times also (up to 40).

**REPRODUCING EXAMPLE**

```
public (???) Method (params)
{ 
 double return_value1 = actions_with_params1;
 double return_value2 = actions_with_params2;
 double[] return_array1 = actions_with_paramsin_a_loop1;
 double[] return_array2 = actions_with_paramsin_a_loop2;
}
```

... and so on. I want to return a variable holding both `double`s and `double[]`s. What should I use better insetafd of `(???)`? Class or struct, regarding performance?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1951243/2324535) excellent answer.

Comment: Honestly, in C# always use a class unless some requirement forces you to use a struct (like interop with native code) or you have run a profiler and found that GC Gen 0 is taking a unacceptable amount of time, and that Gen 0 slowness is caused by it being bloated with thousands of small short lived classes that could be treated with "value type semantics". Other than those two specific cases, just use a class.

Comment: Thank you all! So if during app execution i would create an array of 100 objects returned by my method, i would face performance go down due to the stack got populated, correct?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819), but also know that not all structs live in the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of how I'd do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Container> myValueStorage = new List<Container>();

        for (int i = 1; i < WhateverAmountOfOperations; i++)
        {
            myValueStorage.Add(YourMethod(yourParams));
        }
    }

    public static Container YourMethod(yourParams)
    {
        //Perform your calculations and store your results in the following variables
        double[] double_results; //An array of doubles
        double[][] double_array_results; //An array of double arrays

        //Create and return a class object containing the values
        return new Container(double_results, double_array_results);
    }


}
class Container
{
    double[] _doubles { get; }
    double[][] _double_arrays { get; }
    public Container (double[] doubles, double[][] double_arrays)
    {
        _doubles = doubles;
        _double_arrays = double_arrays;
    }
}
```