# KeyNotFound Exception in Dictionary(of T)

Tags: c#, dictionary, equals, keynotfoundexception

I'm about ready to bang my head against the wall

I have a class called Map which has a dictionary called tiles.

```
class Map
{
    public Dictionary<Location, Tile> tiles = new Dictionary<Location, Tile>();
    public Size mapSize;

    public Map(Size size)
    {
        this.mapSize = size;
    }
   //etc...
```

I fill this dictionary temporarily to test some things..

```
public void FillTemp(Dictionary<int, Item> itemInfo)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i =0; i < mapSize.Width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<mapSize.Height; j++)
            {
                Location temp = new Location(i, j, 0);

                int rint = r.Next(0, (itemInfo.Count - 1));

                Tile t = new Tile(new Item(rint, rint));

                tiles[temp] = t;
            }
        }

    }
```

and in my main program code

```
Map m = new Map(10, 10);
m.FillTemp(iInfo);
Tile t = m.GetTile(new Location(2, 2, 0)); //The problem line
```

now, if I add a breakpoint in my code, I can clearly see that my instance (m) of the map class is filled with  pairs via the function above, but when I try to access a value with the GetTile function:

```
    public Tile GetTile(Location location)
    {
        if(this.tiles.ContainsKey(location))
        {
            return this.tiles[location]; 
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

it ALWAYS returns null. Again, if I view inside the Map object and find the Location key where x=2,y=2,z=0 , I clearly see the value being a Tile that FillTemp generated..

Why is it doing this? I've had no problems with a Dictionary such as this so far. I have no idea why it's returning null. and again, when debugging, I can CLEARLY see that the Map instance contains the Location key it says it does not...
very frustrating.

Any clues? Need any more info?

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote a simple example that showed the problem. I tried to set up a test for this and had to define a number of classes. The final obstacle was that Map defines only a Map(Size size) constructor but the code calls new Map(10, 10). It's difficult to debug code when you can only see part of it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't show what 'Location' is but this is normal behavior if it is a class: objects are tested for Equality by comparing the references. So different instances of Location will always be unequal, even if their content is the same.

The quickest fix is to [override Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) and GetHashCode() for the Location class. And then it is a good idea to (re)design it as an immutable class (or maybe immutable struct).

Comment: Aha, I get understand that completely.

I already had an override of Equals, but I'll look into doing the same for GetHashCode and possibly == and != .. 
Also, I'll look into immutability.. 
thanks much

Comment: @C Patton: If you'd already overridden Equals, you should have received a warning about not overriding GetHashCode. Always check the warnings :)

Answer (score 1):

Henk is correct; when you test to see if two objects are equal in .Net, you're actually asking  if "reference x is pointing to the same object as reference y".

So, by default:

```
Location a = new Location(2, 2, 0);
Location b = new Location(2, 2, 0);
Location c = a;

bool notEqual = ( a == b );  // false
bool equal = ( a == c );     // true
```

To get around this, you need to [override the equality methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502451/c-what-needs-to-be-overriden-in-a-struct-to-ensure-equality-operates-properly/1502479#1502479) for your Location object to compare the values for equality - the body of your `Equals` method, for example, might end us as something like:

```
return (this.x == that.x && this.y == that.y && this.z == that.z);
```

Comment: Yes, but do use a guideline. Several members must be overridden consistently.

Comment: You don't *override* operators, you *overload* them - and you don't actually need to overload == for a type to work in a dictionary for references to equal but distinct objects. You need to override Equals and GetHashCode, which isn't the same thing. It's quite possible to override Equals/GetHashCode without overloading any operators.

Comment: Note that the Microsoft guidelines recommend avoiding overloading equality operators on mutable reference types. You could make Location a value type. You'll also want to overload/override !=, Equals, and GetHashCode, and probably implement IEquatable of T. Which is why I try to avoid going down this road.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - oops, that's embarrassing. I've fixed it now (although in my [poor] defence, the article I linked to is also similarly incorrect).

@Henk Holterman and @TrueWill - these are good points.  The full list of methods that you would need to consider overloading are included in the answer that I linked to, but the OP should also consider making the type immutable or a value type.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! I really appreciate it!

I made Location into a value type and now it's working just fine.

I'm sorry for not posting the whole code, but I didn't feel it was necessary and assumed that the reader could assume that location was a simple class with x,y,z int values.

I learned many new things because of all of you and my understanding of this (generally) wonderful language is greater because of it :o)

Take care,