# Comparing reference types (C#)

Tags: c#, comparison, operator-keyword

I need to compare the values of some reference types that I've created. Which should I override, the Object.Equals method or the == operator? I'm guessing that Object.Equals is the right way to go since I'm not comparing the references themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to override Equals() and GetHashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the Equals() method (and most likely GetHashCode() method as well, to preserve the equivalence)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { ... }

public override int GetHashCode() { ... }
```

[Please see the msdn reference on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Also see this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode)

Answer (score 1):

To go along with what karim said, I recommend you follow the MSDN guidelines for overloading the Equals operator, as well as overload the == operator. This gives you a bit more flexibility on your future usage.