# C# Check if List contains a custom object with the same value

Tags: c#

I have a custom object (the properties must be strings):

```
public class Nemesis
{
    public String Dex_ID;
    public String Value;
}
```

I have a certain function, which creates new instances of that object, adds values to them and then adds them to this List:

```
private List<Nemesis> _nemesisList;
public List<Nemesis> NemesisList
{
    get { return _nemesisList; }
    set { _nemesisList = value; }
}
```

Normally, I'd use this to check for existing things:

```
if (!NemesisList.Contains(nemesis))
{
    NemesisList.Add(nemesis);
}
```

But this time I want to check if my List already contains a **nemesis** with the same **nemesis.Dex_ID**. How do I do that?

Comment: `NemesisList.Any(n=>n.Dex_ID==IdToCheck)` would return true if any list elements match the given `IdToCheck`

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Thank you :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you only want to to check against the the ID field and ignore others then you can do :

```
if(!NemesisList.Any(n=> n.Dex_ID == nemesis.Dex_ID))
```

otherwise if you want to perform comparison for all the fields then you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

See: [Correct way to override Equals() and GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode)

Comment: Beat me to it! This is how you would do it Kohnarik

Comment: Thanks, I love you. have my babies

Comment: Uhh, one more question. If I now find a nemesis with the same Dex_ID, how do I access the found nemesis? Let's act like "n" is the found nemesis. example: `...else { n.Dex_ID = n.Dex_ID + nemesis.Dex_ID }`

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` read about it, it should be like: `var item = NemesisList.FirstOrDefault(n=> n.Dex_ID == nemesis.Dex_ID);` and then modify your check like `if(item == null) {//not found } else {//found, work with item.Dex_ID....}`

Comment: I think `Single()` is way more idiomatic here. `OrDefault` is wrong imo, since we KNOW the item is in the list, if it isn't we know we have a bug, so we want to fail fast. I still think a dictionary is better here though.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
if (!NemesisList.Any(n => n.Dex_ID == nemesis.Dex_ID)) // ...
```

OR

```
if (!NemesisList.Select(n => n.Dex_ID).Contains(nemesis.Dex_ID)) // ...
```

The better solution is probably to create a dictionary though. They are built for quick lookups based on some key value.

```
if (!NemesisDict.ContainsKey(nemesis.Dex_ID)) // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is your friend here:

```
if (!myList.Any(x => x.Dex_ID == nemesis.Dex_ID)) myList.Add(nemesis)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following LINQ:

```
var exists = NemesisList.Any(n=>n.Dex_Id==id)
```