# C# Object not found in Dictionary<T, T>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary. I use this code to get the index of the object:

```
type.Name = _shuffledClasses.Where(entry => entry.Key.Name.Equals(originName))
                            .Where(entry => entry.Key.Namespace.Equals(type.Namespace))
                            .Select(item => item.Value).GetEnumerator().Current.Name;
```

But it doesn't find the Object. I double checked if the Object is create correctly and if it exists, and it does! The Object in question is in the 'Key' column and I wan't to get the object in the 'Value' column.

I tried also this piece of code, which doesn't work aswell:

```
type.Name = _shuffledClasses[new Classes()
{
     Name = originName,
     Namespace = type.Namespace
}].Name;
```

My "Classes" Object looks as follows:

```
class Classes
{
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Why wont it find the Object?

I did some research and I tried overriding Equals and GetHashCode, now my class looks like this and still doesn't work:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Classes fooItem = obj as Classes;
    return fooItem == this;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in your class, which is required for it to work as key in `Dictionary` and `HashSet`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Do I need to override Equals also if I use the second version?

Comment: The second version is the one that needs `GetHashCode`/`Equals` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is fundamentally broken right here:

```
.GetEnumerator().Current.Name;
```

The enumerator needs to be moved one element ahead with `MoveNext()` or `Current` will not have any value.

Also, enumerators should be disposed. Try this instead:

```
type.Name = _shuffledClasses.Where(entry => entry.Key.Name.Equals(originName))
                            .Where(entry => entry.Key.Namespace.Equals(type.Namespace))
                            .Select(item => item.Value)
                            .First().Name;
```

If you don't want to use `First()` for whatever reason, you can also iterate manually like this:

```
using (var enumerator = _shuffledClasses.Where(entry => entry.Key.Name.Equals(originName))
                            .Where(entry => entry.Key.Namespace.Equals(type.Namespace))
                            .Select(item => item.Value).GetEnumerator()) {
    enumerator.MoveNext(); // maybe check here if the operation is successful!
    type.Name = enumerator.Current.Name;
}
```

Comment: I thought this before, that's why I tried another solution. Any thoughts on the second version?

Comment: You're welcome. Nevertheless, to look up a dictionary value with a key you should properly make the key class equatable as shown by Marcin and Gilad - the lookup will be **much** more efficient that way!

Answer (score 2):

> Why wont it find the Object?

Because you didn't override GetHashCode and Equals in your class, which is required for it to work as key in Dictionary and HashSet

> `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` requires an equality implementation to determine whether keys are equal. You can specify an implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter; **if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic equality comparer `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is used**. If type `TKey` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

And this generic comparer uses reference equality if your type does not implement `IEquatable<T>`.

You can try using LINQ and `First` if you don't want to implement your custom equality, but that will defeat the purpose of using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` because you'll have to scan the entire collection to get that value:

```
shuffledClasses.First(x => x.Key.Name == myName && x.Key.Value == myValue).Value
```

Comment: Where did you find that information? To me it looks like the `Key` is custom `Classes` class.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I stopped reading the code after the first version. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `Dictionary` the clearest way of finding a `Key` in it is by using the `[]` or by `TryGetValue`.

Using linq is great but in my opinion this is not a place to use it. Searching a `key` in a dictionary is a `o(1)` operation but using linq the way you did turns it to a `o(n)`. If you can override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` or supply a custom `IEquatable<>` I think it is better.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<Classes, string> data = new Dictionary<Classes, string>
    {
        [new Classes { Name = "a", Namespace = "a" }] = "first",
        [new Classes { Name = "b", Namespace = "b" }] = "second",
    };

    var key = new Classes { Name = "a", Namespace = "a" };

    string result1 = data[key]; // "first"


    string result2;
    if (data.TryGetValue(key, out result2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result2); // 'first"
    }
}

class Classes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Classes;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return other.Name == Name &&
               other.Namespace == Namespace;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode() ^
               Namespace.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

The problem with your implementation of the overriding of the methods is:

1. Equals - after casting you are still not actually comparing the properties

   ```
   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       Classes fooItem = obj as Classes;
       return fooItem == this;
   }
   ```
2. GetHashCode - You gave no implementation to it.. Still using the `GetHashCode` of `object`

   ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       return base.GetHashCode();
   }
   ```

For further references see:

1. MSDN - [Implementing the Equals Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx)
2. Stackoverflow - [Correct way to override Equals() and GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode)
3. Stackoverflow - [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)