# GroupBy all fields and get count

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name  {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string City  {get; set;}
}
```

Customer Collection

```
List<Customer> customers = //assigned range of customers
```

Now I need to group by **all fields**. I don't want to select individual fields. In my actual scenario, it runs more dynamic, so I cannot predefine the fields.

From this `customers` object I need to construct a matrix like

```
Name |   Email    | City | count
AB     ef@g.com     ss      3
CB      f@g.com     ss      2
EF      k@s.com     ss      34
ek      g.com       we      84
```

I tried going this route.
Extension method to group by multiple columns

```
public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, List<string> groupSelectors)
{
    var selectors =
        new List<Func<TElement, object>>(groupSelectors.Count);
    foreach (var selector in groupSelectors)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression =
            System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(TElement), typeof(object), $"it[\"{selector}\"]");
        selectors.Add((Func<TElement, object>) lambdaExpression.Compile());
    }
    return elements.GroupByMany(selectors.ToArray());
}
```

and call it like

```
customers.GroupByMany(displayFields);
```

Problem is I am getting the results as nested groups

```
public class GroupResult
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupResult> SubGroups { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Key} ({Count})";
    }
}
```

That is going away from what I need again.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work.

Comment: What is the `count` of? Please show what you have tried so far. And what do you mean by matrix? Is that a C# object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking or trying to do here. Do you just want to output them?

Comment: I need to construct a List<dynamic> customers with additional count field. @Peter count is the count of duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group by the entire object and count occurrences (or in other words "count duplicates") just group by the iterated item like this:

```
var result = from item in customers
             group 1 by item into grouping
             select new {
                 grouping.Key,
                 Count = grouping.Count()
             };
```

For sample data of:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { Name = "a", City = "a" },
    new Customer { Name = "a", City = "a" },
    new Customer { Name = "a", City = "b" },
    new Customer { Name = "b", City = "b" }
};
```

Result is:

[image]

*Notice that grouping by the `Customer` object uses its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for comparing the objects then make sure to override them. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9317582/6400526)*

*Also see that all properties of the object are properties in `Key` which does not align with your example output but does align with the provided `GroupResult` you showed*

Comment: I think I was over-complicating my requirement. Thanks @Gilad

Comment: @HaBo - Did this work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @HaBo you are welcome :) glad it helped