# C# join items which are the same with lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, nopcommerce

With the following code how would I join items together.

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
    .Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
    .Select(x => x.ShipmentItems)
    .ToList();
```

So there may be two or more shipments for the order id.
Each shipment may contain identical items.

Need a nudge in the right direction

Have tried

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
    .Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
    .Select(x => x.ShipmentItems.Join(x.ShipmentItems
        .Where(y => y.ShipmentId == shipment.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

and

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
    .Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
    .Select(x => x.ShipmentItems.GroupBy(y => y.Id))
    .ToList();
```

and

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
    .Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
    .Select(x => x.ShipmentItems.Distinct())
    .ToList();
```

Here is the code I'm using for output the items:

```
foreach (var shipmentItem in shippedItems)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("item = " + shipmentItem);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("item = " + shipmentItem.OrderItemId);
}
```

The above output produces:

> shippedItemsList count = 9 item =
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356077
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356078
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356079
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356077
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356078
>
> item =
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356079
>
> item =
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356077
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356079
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356080

So the excepted output should be:

> shippedItemsList count = 4 
>   item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356077
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356079
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356078
>
> item = System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ShipmentItem_18BEAAFA747B42988EC4CB25D967298CC6736AF528389FC98E81143F7D629631
>   item = 356080

The above output is from using `var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId).SelectMany(x => x.ShipmentItems).ToList();`

NOTE: shipment item is `ICollection<ShipmentItem> Shipment.ShipmentItems` when I hover it in visual studio

UPDATED senario:

So let's say that the order has 3 items(a = 3, b= 5, c = 3), Now 1 shipment is sent with items(a = 1, b = 2, c = 0), Now a second shipment is sent with items(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1). I would like the quantity of items from both shipments. So I expect items(a = 2, b = 3, c = 1), I currently get items(a = 1, b = 2) + items(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1). So the list of shipment items I loop through are appearing more than once.

I thought maybe union but not sure how to put it together :/

> UPDATE MY SOLUTION
>
> I could not manage to accomplish this using lambda expression, so I
>   had to do the following solution to get the result I wanted. I hope
>   this helps others looking for workarounds.
>
> ```
> //calculate quantity of total shipped items from each shipment
>             List<ShipmentItem> alreadyShippedItemsList = new List<ShipmentItem>();
>             Dictionary<int, int> alreadyShippedItems = new Dictionary<int, int>();
>
>             var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
>             .Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null)
>             .SelectMany(x => x.ShipmentItems)
>             .ToList();
>
>             //create a list of shipment items
>             for (int i = 1; i <= shipmentsList.Count - 1; i++)
>             {
>                 var si = shipmentsList[i];
>
>                 var sii = si.ShipmentItems.ToList();
>
>                 foreach (var item in sii)
>                 {
>                     var itemInList = alreadyShippedItemsList.Where(x => x.OrderItemId == item.OrderItemId).FirstOrDefault();
>                     int sum = 0;
>
>                     //create a list of shipment items and check for duplicate items
>                     if (itemInList == null)
>                     {
>                         alreadyShippedItems.Add(item.OrderItemId, item.Quantity);
>                         alreadyShippedItemsList.Add(item);
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         //if duplicate item is found update the quantity in the dictionary
>                         sum = itemInList.Quantity + item.Quantity;
>                         alreadyShippedItems[item.OrderItemId] = sum;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: Depend on your requirement, is this "Join", or "Union". Perharp if you can provide your data, and your required output, it should be easier for us

Comment: @Jacky see my updated question, have added required output.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier so 1 order may have 3 shipments, each shipment can have any number of items from the order.

Comment: So I want all items from all shipments join together

Comment: Consider that a Shipment contains unique ShipmentItems but shared OrderItems.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx), which flattens a `list`

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
.SelectMany(x => x.ShipmentItems)
.ToList();
```

Comment: This is still not working as expected. See my updated question, have example of output I should be getting. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This appears to be the correct solution from my googling. But the list is not flattened, so the same item is appearing in the list more than once. :(

Comment: Perhaps you need to apply a `.Where` to the `ShippingItems`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Distinct in the wrong place

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
.Select(x => x.ShipmentItems).Distinct()
.ToList();
```

Either override Equals function for the ShipmentItems class using this [Correct way to override Equals() and GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode) and use distinct directly or do two steps

```
 var distinctShippedItemIds = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId)
.Select(x => x.ShipmentItems.OrderItemId).Distinct()
.ToList();

List<ShippingItems> UniqueItemList=new List<ShippingItems>();
 foreach(int OrderId in distinctShippedItemIds)
 {
     var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments
.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == OrderId)
.Select(x => x.ShipmentItems).FirstOrDefault();
      if(shippedItems !=null)
      {
         UniqueItemList.Add(shippedItems);
      }
 }
```

Comment: damn i thought ShipmentItems was an Int property

Comment: Distinct is not working because, runtime doesnt know what makes two shipmentitems equals. you will have to override the equals() and gethashcodemethod() of your ShipmentItems class give this information to runtime. use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode

Comment: Nah shipment item is `ICollection<ShipmentItem> Shipment.ShipmentItems` when I hover it. This has me stumpped :(

Comment: did you override the equals method in your shipmentitems class? should solve your problem

Comment: The part of your edit can be done in one statement. See my answer

Comment: but as mentioned the best and easiest way is to override the equals function.

Comment: Distinct on ShipmentItems only makes sense if you fetch the same Shipment more than once since ShipmentItems are always bound to one Shipment. A distinct to the OrderItem of the ShipmentItem makes sense, cause there can be multiple ShipmentItems for one OrderItem. Check Edit 2 of my Answer

Comment: See my updated question for the solution which worked for me. This was helpful though. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I may get you wrong but is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM [ShipmentItem]
INNER JOIN [Shipment] ON [ShipmentItem].[ShipmentId] = [Shipment].[Id]
WHERE [Shipment].[ShippedDateUtc] IS NOT NULL AND [Shipment].[OrderId] = @OrderId
```

So this will do the job

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(orderId)
        .Shipments
        .Where(s => s.ShippedDateUtc != null)
        .SelectMany(s => s.ShipmentItems)
        .ToList();
```

Sample
[image: ShipmentItems at database]
[image: ShipmentItems at VS]

**Edit**

If You you want to fetch the order items you have to do something like this

```
var orderItems = _orderService
    .GetOrderById(orderId)
    .Shipments
    .Where(s => s.ShippedDateUtc != null)
    .SelectMany(s => s.ShipmentItems)
    .Select(si => _orderService.GetOrderItemById(si.OrderItemId))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

or if you want to  produces less DB queries

```
var orderItems = _orderService
    .GetOrderById(orderId)
    .Shipments
    .Where(s => s.ShippedDateUtc != null)
    .SelectMany(s => s.ShipmentItems)
    .Select(si => si.OrderItemId)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(id => _orderService.GetOrderItemById(id))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit 2**

nopCommerce data of a order with 4 order items (quantity of 2) and 4 shipments
[image: DB Structure]

Comment: The second bit of code lambda expression code does not work. So let's say that the order has 3 items(a = 3, b= 5, c = 3), Now 1 shipment is sent with items(a = 1, b = 2, c = 0), Now a second shipment is sent with items(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1). I would like the quantity of items from both shipments. So I expect items(a = 2, b = 3, c = 1), I currently get items(a = 1, b = 2) + items(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1). So the list of shipment items I loop through are appearing more than once. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for helping

Comment: In order to get quantities of both shipments you have to group ShipmentItems by OrderItemId and count Quantity together

Comment: See my updated question for the solution which worked for me, for some reason your solution would not work for me. Thanks for your help though :)