# Find in List<object> where each item is in an array

Tags: c#

I'm making a web service call and getting data back that I am adding to a list. No problems doing that. My `remedyinfo` list has content that I can verify with break points in VS.

I cannot seem to figure out how to search the list for a value that matches a new variable, for instance I want to find if `incidentID` is equal to "INC000000001".

I've tried `var foundItem = remedyinfo.Contains("searchvalue")` but it always returns `false`.

I've tried the LINQ queries as suggested in other post:

```
var foundItem = myArray.SingleOrDefault(item => item.intProperty == someValue);
```

What I do notice is that the sample refers to comparing `item.intProperty == somevalue)` should work, I am not able to get any reference after `item.`, only suggested `Equals`, `GetType`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`. So, I cannot reference `item.incidentID` for example.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
var remedyinfo = new List<object> { };

remedyinfo.Add(new IncidentItem()
  {
      assignedgroup = assignedgroup,
      incidentID = incidentID,
      submitdate = offsetDate.ToString(),
      priority = priority,
      status = status,
      assignee = assignee,
      summarydesc = summarydesc,
      notes = notes
  });

    [Serializable]
    public class IncidentItem
    {
        public string assignedgroup { get; set; }
        public string incidentID { get; set; }
        public string submitdate { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string assignee { get; set; }
        public string summarydesc { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `List<object>` needs to be `List<IncidentItem>` to use the LINQ query you referenced.

Comment: `List<object>` is almost never a good idea, why are you using that instead of `List<IncidentItem>`?

Comment: @JSteward appreciate the info on that.

Answer (score 0):

To check if list contains an item, there are different options. You can use Any in .Net 3.5 or higher:

```
if (remedyinfo.Any(incident => incident.incidentID == "Hello"))
// rest of code
```

If you have another IncidentItem and wish to check in list like

```
var anotherIncident = new IncidentItem();
if (remedyInfo.Contains(anotherIncident))
```

then you either have to implement `IEquatable` or override `Equals` and `HashCode` in `IncidentItem` class.
More on Equals and HashCode is here:

[Correct way to override Equals() and GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode)