# C# - Determine if all values of a single element in a list of objects are in another list

Tags: c#, list

Currently I am working with something similar to the following:

```
if(listA.All(x => x.myHouseNumber == "1" || x.myValue == "2")
{
//do something
}
```

listA is a list of elements (myName, myHouseNumber, myStreet)

basically, I want the condition to be true if every myHouseNumber in listA is found in listB which is just a list of numbers

So if listA contains Bill,1,Main and Ted,2,Second
and listB contains 1,2,3 the condition is true because 1 and 2 are found within list B.  if listB contained 1,5,9 the condition would be false because 2 is missing.

I am having trouble understanding how to compare a list with a single item to a single element in a list with several items.

The end result I am hoping would be something like this which I cannot seem to get to work

```
if(listA.All(x => x.myHouseNumber.Contains(listB.Any())))
{
//do something
}
```

Hopefully someone will understand what I am going for and be able to provide some assistance

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try implementing the IEqualityComparer interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482533/compare-two-list-using-linq-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand is correct, you should use the listB contains myHouseNumber.

the demo code.

```
public class test { 
 public string myName;
 public string myHouseNumber;
 public string myStreet; 
}
var listA = new List<test> 
{ new test { myHouseNumber = "1", myName = "Bill", myStreet = "Main" },
 new test { myHouseNumber = "2", myName = "Ted", myStreet = "Second" }
};
var listB = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
var listC = new List<string> { "1", "5", "9" };
// it is true
listA.All(p => listB.Contains(p.myHouseNumber))
// it is false
istA.All(p => listC.Contains(p.myHouseNumber))
```