# "Equals" cannot be called in the overload operator function?

Tags: c#, .net

I found an interesting thing, take this as a C# program:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object comparedStudent)
        {
            Student stu = comparedStudent as Student;

            if (stu == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return ID.Equals(stu.ID) && Name.Equals(stu.Name);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ID.GetHashCode() ^ Name.GetHashCode();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Notice that this will cause NullPointException……Why?
        /// If I use "return s1.ID==s2.ID && s1.Name==s2.Name", that'd be OK.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool operator ==(Student s1, Student s2)
        {
            return s1.Equals(s2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Student s1, Student s2)
        {
            return !s1.Equals(s2);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student s1 = new Student();
            s1.ID = 1;
            s1.Name = "YourName";
            Student s2 = new Student();
            s2.ID = 1;
            s2.Name = "YourName";

            //Why there's an exception here (NullPoint exception)
            bool isSame = (s1 == s2);
            Console.WriteLine(isSame);
        }
    }
}
```

If you copy my codes and run, a NullPointer exception will be thrown out. Why?

PS：If I use "return s1.ID==s2.ID && s1.Name==s2.Name" in the overload operator +, that'd be OK.

Why? I'm using net4.0 VS2015.

And if you debug by dropping the debug point at "bool isSame = (s1 == s2);" You'll soon find it enters into the "==" overload function 3 times, and in the end, s1 and s2 are null!

Comment: Instead of `stu == null` use `object.ReferenceEquals(stu, null)`

Comment: @IanMercer: But why the operator function is called 3 times in debugging? And in the end, both s1=s2=null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Ians comment will fix the above issue it will not finally fix the problem in general.
The origin of the problem is in the overload of the comparison operators.

A programmer expects `null == myobject` as well as `myobject == null` to be a valid expression (as you did as well in implementation of `.Equals`). This does not work for the above class because of the invocation of the member function `s1.Equals` in `operator ==`.

So any reasonable overload of a comparison operator should be able to handle really **any input** without throwing an exception. In doubt simply return false.
This includes null values as well as class instances that do not yet have all properties assigned.

```
public static bool operator ==(Student s1, Student s2) =>
  ReferenceEquals(s1, s2) || (!ReferenceEquals(s1, null) && s1.Equals(s2));
```

Rationale:

- `ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)` handles `null == null` as well as `x == x`. The latter does not require to compare the content.
- `s1 != null` handles `null == x`.
- `x == null` is already handled by the `.Equals` implementation.

By the way: it is recommended to provide a strongly typed `.Equals` implementation when overloading equality operators by implementing `IEquatable<Student>`.

Furthermore you should not use `.Equals` to compare components, because this will sadly fail for a similar reason if `Name` has not been assigned so far.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
  Equals(obj as Student);

public bool Equals(Student stu) =>
  !ReferenceEquals(stu, null) && ID == stu.ID && Name == stu.Name;
```

See also the reply of Yuval Itzchakov to question [Operator overloading ==, !=, Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461585/operator-overloading-equals)

Comment: It's `IEquatable<T>`. There's no such interface `IEqualityComparable<T>` (though there *is* an `IEqualityComparer<T>` but it's purpose is somewhat different)