# Are there "Records" in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, record

I'm looking to store some customer data in memory, and I figure the best way to do that would be to use an array of records. I'm not sure if that's what its called in C#, but basically I would be able to call `Customer(i).Name` and have the customers name returned as a string. In turing, its done like this:

```
type customers :
    record
        ID : string
        Name, Address, Phone, Cell, Email : string
        //Etc...
    end record
```

I've searched, but I can't seem to find an equivalent for C#. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Create a new class to store those fields.

Comment: .NET has array and many types of collections.  Search MSDN array and collection.

Comment: 2020 update: C# now has record types.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, well that would be defined in a `class` in C#, so it might look like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cell { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could have a `List<T>` of those:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();

customers.Add(new Customer
{
    ID = "Some value",
    Name = "Some value",
    ...
});
```

and then you could access those by index if you wanted:

```
var name = customers[i].Name;
```

**UPDATE:** as stated by [`psibernetic`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909954/psibernetic), the [`Record`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) class in F# provides field level equality out of the gate rather than referential equality. This is a very important distinction. To get that same equality operation in C# you'd need to make this `class` a `struct` and then produce the operators necessary for equality; a great example is found as an answer on this question [What needs to be overridden in a struct to ensure equality operates properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502451/what-needs-to-be-overriden-in-a-struct-to-ensure-equality-operates-properly).

Comment: `name` is a very strange name for a `Customer` :)

Comment: `var name = customers[i];` looks strange naming convention isn't it? `var customer = customers[i];` would be good.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yeah I meant to end that statement by accessing the `Name` property like the OP did in the question. I saw what you meant afterwards and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this should work perfectly! Where in my code would I put this though if I want to be able to access the values anywhere in the program? If I put it in form2.cs but set it to public, is it usable by any form?

Comment: @user2856410, put the class in its own file. The class is `public` so its accessible to the entire assembly as well as consumers of the assembly.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll have to play around with this for a bit to figure it all out, but it should work just fine. I'll post another question if I have any problems. Thanks guys! :)

Comment: @user2856410 Should note that while the class is public, you'd probably want to pass the List of customers from form to form. Otherwise you'd have to make a new List on each form and re-populate it.

The customer class is just the "template" to store all of the customer info, the List is what actually has the meat and veggies of the data.

Comment: This overlooks what is the refining factor of structure types in F#: structural equality instead of reference.

Example:
type RecordTest = { X: int; Y: int }
let record1 = { X = 1; Y = 2 }
let record2 = { X = 1; Y = 2 }

record1 and record2 are equal because their contexts are equal, similar to struct in C#, but with implied equality operators.

You can do this in C# with a struct, but you will have to define equality and inequality operators.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx

Comment: @psibernetic: that's a very good addition! I'll update for those reading in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A class or a struct would work here.

```
    class Customer
    {
        string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    Customer[] customers = new Customer[50];
    //after initializing the array elements, you could do
    //assuming a for loop with i as index
    Customer currentCustomer = customers[i];
    currentCustomer.Name = "This";
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the "type" you are looking for is actually a Class.

```
class Customer {
  string id, name, phone, cell, email;
}

List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
```

Check this link for more detail on classes... you may want to do a bit of research, reading and learning :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class which models your customers, you can simply use a List of customers.

```
var c = new List<Customers>()

string name = c[i].Name
```