# Using Lists and Classes

Tags: c#, .net

As recommended in my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280807/are-there-records-in-c), the best way to store customer data would be in a list of class instances (I think thats what it's called :p). I've created the list `var customers = new List<Customer>();` in a startup method, and right after, when I load any values from a text file into the program, I'm doing this:

```
static void loadData() //Load data from Database
{            
    customers.Add(new Customer
    {
        ID = "001",
        Name = "Nathan",
    }
}
```

I know I'm not doing it correctly though, and I can't quite figure out the correct way. Right now I'm not extracting from the file, I'm just trying to add something to the list. Obviously I'm missing a closing parenthesis, but I'm not quite sure where it would go.

If someone could help me add one thing to this list, I should be able to figure out the rest on my own.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

`.Add()` is a method and there is a parenthesis missing.

```
static void loadData() //Load data from Database
{            
    customers.Add(new Customer
    {
        ID = "001",
        Name = "Nathan",
    });
}
```

It may be a good habit for you, to write the methods first, including the parenthesis and add all the parameters afterwards into it. This way you would eliminate those errors.

What I mean is:

Start with `customers.Add();`

Then add the new Customer class instance: `customers.Add(new Customer {});`

And finally add your actual data `customers.Add(new Customer { //Here'll be dragons});`

Comment: :facepalm: I should have been able to figure that out! If you can't tell, I still don't quite know what I'm doing :P

Thanks again!

Comment: Everybody has started out somewhere. Keep on going, you will get the hang of it fairly soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
   static void loadData() //Load data from Database
    {            
        customers.Add(new Customer{ ID = "001", Name = "Nathan" });
    }
```